# Why wasn't the room with the crystalline Spantium being reset?

Tags: plot-explanation, doctor-who

In Heaven Sent (Doctor Who):

As every room in the castle was being reset after a while, why wasn't the room with the crystalline Spantium being reset? Each hit by the Doctor wearing away the wall should have been undone the next time he arrived there.

Comment: Why did the "reset" include an old painting of Clara, a dirty shovel, a floor tile buried in the yard, and the remains of his previous self along with his final message in the dust?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### He was only meant to go there once, and it's the only room connected to the outside.

Room 12 has a markedly different appearance to the rest of the castle: in particular, the unusually smooth walls and large block of azbantium. This is the 'final' room.

The castle is designed to get the Doctor to reveal the identity of the Hybrid. The designers thought he would only arrive in the trap room once, realise it’s impossible to escape, give up, and tell the secret. They almost certainly didn't anticipate the Doctor chipping away at the wall over billions of years. And if he’s only supposed to visit this room once, then there’s no need for the room to reset.

Also, note that this room connects to the outside world, and is apparently the only room to do so. So it makes sense for the rules to be a bit different here. It may even have been impossible for the designers to make this room reset every time, since it's connected to the outside and the outside can't be 'reset' in this way.

<sub>Much of this answer is copied from the excellent answer by @alexwlchan on [another Stack Exchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/108985/31394).</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because the creator of the island made that room and thought that the Doctor wouldn't figure it out so it just doesn't need to be reset. Or since the room is designated to him specifically so it doesn't have to reset. But IDK those are just my explanations, is that good enough.

Answer (score -1):

Because Time Lords don't know the tales of the Grimm Brothers, making them believe, the Azbantium cant't be changed or altered in any way, making it useless to reset it.  Or: only stuff that is made, is resetted, thuff that is made of nature itself never did(the sea, never resetted to get rif of the skulls, the stars never resetted them to be in the same place, and so did the Azbantium, because the only thing that can't be resetted is Time, the painting got older, the stars moved, the skulls (since a body normally dies of age, or other time inflicted matters) and so on.  The flower, a living organisme, has been cut off,  and has lost it's connection to it's life in nature.